# Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: build.gradle

What should i do to fix this issue?
I am getting this error when i ever i run my project in android studio0.9.1

```
android {compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.nearby"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')}
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Please check:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32685132/1495235

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Please check [my answer here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32685132/1495235

Comment: @Traveller just for future reference, to link in comments, use this syntax: `[text](link)`

Comment: I had the same problem and found a solution, [check this answer!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33904563/3527780)

Comment: [You can try it from stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0) by Jared Burrows' answer.Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 108):

I just ran into this same error. Make sure you don't have an `android` block in the top-level build.gradle for the project, only in the module's build.gradle file.

This happened to me when AndroidStudio tried to import and existing, buildable Eclipse/ADT project–I had to cut and paste the `android` block from one gradle file to the other. I don't know if this has been fixed in more recent versions of AndroidStudio.

Comment: first thing i was working on the low level build.gradle, which is wrong, second, i used this code at the end

Comment: (Might be nice to accept this answer, if you feel it is useful.)

Comment: @Youri I could use some more details on what you did to fix this. I can't figure it out.

Comment: I might point out, as an addendum, that this happened to me when AndroidStudio tried to import and existing, buildable Eclipse/ADT project–I had to cut and paste the `android` block from one gradle file to the other. I don't know if this has been fixed in more recent versions of AndroidStudio.

Comment: additionally remove any code like:
dependencies {
}

Comment: @KemalettinErbakırcı Have you seen AndroidStudio auto-generating dependencies blocks and that causing errors? Is is this just a common mistake you've seen people make?

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem. My fix was adding "apply plugin: 'android'" before android block...
Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Ionoclast Brigham's answer I've checked both gradle files. I had android() in both of them... but instead of moving android() from the root one to module one I've just added

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

to root one and build works fine.

Answer (score 2):

in my case i had to  delete these lines from the top-level **build.gradle** file as it's a **bug in the android studio** which inserts this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: If I remove these lines it justs asks me to install android API again

Comment: In which build.gradle are you removing it.

Comment: You have to do the charge in the root build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0)  under **runProguard** section. In short, it says;

To update your project, edit your build.gradle file as follows:

```
}
     release {
         runProguard true
         minifyEnabled true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
```