# android studio 1.4.1 Error:(15, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ndk()'

Tags: android-studio

i am following this tutorial online

https://youtu.be/kFtxo7rr2HQ

and when I tried to build I keep gettingt his:

Error:(15, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'ndk()'
Possible causes:

The project 'NDKTest' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

I have tried this thread:

[Android Studio Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' -- Error(17,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0)

but it is pretty old now.

here's my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.guitarv.www.ndktest"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

ndk {

            moduleName = "HelloJNI"
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Android Studio 1.4.1
android-ndk-r10e

Anyone knows what is going on?

thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the ndk to the defaultConfig scope. Maybe, you'll want to add the sourceSets.main scope too

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.guitarv.www.ndktest"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            moduleName = "HelloJNI"
        }
        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/libs"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```