# Gradle DSL method not found 'android()' error android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am new in Android studio.

I have getting gradle DSL method not found error after adding lib file

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```

below are the code build.gradle code which i get error.

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```

there are two build.gradle one is app and other is library.

[image]

Comment: post your gradle code

Comment: I have not change in gradel file.

Comment: but you have to post it , inorder to solve it

Comment: your answer is given......  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0

Comment: i used that code not working

Comment: any suggesstion for this

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `build.gradle` file

In your **top-level** file **you can't use** the `android` block:

**Just remove this part from the first build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {

}
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```