# Error with importing Telegram into Android Studio (using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, telegram

I am newbie:) and trying to import `telegram` application into my Android Studio.

And now i have this error i can't solve it anyway.

```
Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Telegram-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

**The Build.gradle :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
android {
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
dependencies {
}
```

**Gradle.properties :**

```
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=password
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=alias
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=password
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Tue Jun 16 02:56:07 KRAT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip
```

I've searched stack for this buT i couldn't solve it.

How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0