# Android NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

When i run my codes Adroid studio gives that error

my gradle file like under below    and   Android Studio v2.2   gradle  is 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asd.asd"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.3.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries false
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile project(':mPChartLib')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        compile files('libs/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/pushwoosh-4.0.4.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'



    }


05-30 20:41:50.785 14551-14551/com.asd.asd/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                     Process: com.asd.asd, PID: 14551
                                                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1638)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1609)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5008)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4582)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

idont use any firebase application but i got this error. so i try somany tecnique which are found on internet . but noting change .

can you help me pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first update your `Google Repository` in your sdk 
second enable `multidex`  like

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

compile with

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: when i add  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'  . i got an error     Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'

Comment: @çağrıGündüz read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851467/4824159  AND http://stackoverflow.com/a/27735956/4824159

Comment: try  compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.+'`

Comment: İt works but now i  when program starts i got this error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)

Comment: which AS version you used and update your all google Repository in your as sdk

Answer (score 3):

This bug is reported with newer versions mostly arround Revision 28,29 and its resolved in newer Play services versions so very first if you having this issue then make sure you have updated version of Google Play service in your Android studio.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to  Android SDK Manager
2. Go to Extra

[image]

And update it to **version 30** or later.

Then if **you are using MultiDex** in your Application then please use it only if it's compulsory.

Make sure you have follow these steps when integrating MultiDex.

In you **App level Build.Gradle**

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reversebits.tapanhp.saffer"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

**Apply MultiDex dependency** in `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Then inside your **AndroidMenifest.xml** file make sure that **Application tag have name of MultiDexApplication**.

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

### Note

**if you have custom Application class** and using it in your menifest file then you can **initialize multidex in your Application class** as follows,

```
public class AppClass extends Application {
    private static Context context;
    private static AppClass mInstance;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your top-level build.gradle you have to add:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Then in your module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ... 

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

1, Open your SDK Manager then install **Google Play Services (rev 30)** and **Google Repository (rev 26)**.

2, Add  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to your build.gradle of project.

Answer (score 0):

You should include Multidex library to your gradle.build

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

And as suggested by @Lollipop you need to download  Google play Services and add classpath in your project. Since Firebase need this library to work properly.

**EDIT**

```
buildscript 
{ 
dependencies 
 { 
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' 
 } 
}
```

Comment: when i add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' . i got an error Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'

Comment: you should be adding classpath under 'buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}' in gradle.build file