# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions (unable to build on certain device)

Tags: android, exception, firebase

I had included multidex. The project work on other device like emulator and samsung S5 but its not working on Sumsung GT. 
So i wondering is that anyway to make it work on this samsung device.Or what may be the problem here?

following the the error code

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4725)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4665)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
```

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and my gradle build look like this

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:+'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Never upload images with code, just copy paste and use "the code option"

Comment: ohh sorry was new to stack overflow. Will edit it soon

Comment: Don't use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2`  because it makes your application easily reach 64k limitation. Select only google API that you need. Read more at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Ohh i see. It is possible that due to the limitation that caused the application not being able the build on certain device?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360126/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseop)? Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535141/android-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-firebase-firebaseoptions)

Comment: Yes i had seen both of them. I had enable the multidex and the google play service clash path are updated.