# How to fix "Error:Error:line (23)Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I was working on my project in Android Studio on Windows but now I am trying to open it on Ubuntu but it keeps complaining that:

```
Error:Error:line (23)Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' Possible causes: //(Error23,0)

The project 'POSTER' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin
```

**Project Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
}
```

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ozuf.poster"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.5 Beta"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile project(':volley')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0-RC-2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Apr 08 19:27:52 WAT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Please, do you have any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Same Question with Answer help you to solve: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0                                                                               2. https://medium.com/@marcuspereira/solving-the-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-in-android-studio-6e5ab499bd3#.y27dt11gb

Comment: @priyanshbhaliya thnks the medium link solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete android settings in project gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
}
```

if you want to set as common config, you can use is like this:

project gralde:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
}
```

app gralde:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ozuf.poster"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.5 Beta"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```