# Gradle project refresh failed in Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I created sample project on the fresh installation of the Android Studio v 1.2.1.1 and i faced with this error message:

```
Gradle project refresh failed in Android Studio 1.2.1.1
```

See image below:

[image]

So i tried to find any solution on the Google and i checked

**gradle.properties** file

where is:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

After that i tried to update all SDK libraries using SDK manager

And after that i tried to find issue in settings (see image)

But everything without success. Because in the error description is nothing i don't know what can be wrong and what to repair.

Any idea please?

Many thanks for any help.

**Note:**
Compilaton using Cordova (which is using Gradle too) is without problems and app is compiled.

[image]

Comment: Really nobody knows?

Comment: I would always suggest running gradlew via command line when in doubt.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who is struggling with this error, here is my solution:

**Step 1)** Click in "Android Studio" (upper bar) -> "Preferences" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "Gradle"

And select "Use local gradle distribution" and find the path for your Gradle file
(eg. /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.8)

**Step 2)** Click in "File" (upper bar) -> "Project Structure" -> Select "app" in the "Modules" section.
Then, make sure you have set the Compiler SDK Version and Build Tools Version

**Step 3)** Open your project -> Open "build.gradle" file and then remove the following lines:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion 'XX.X.X'
}
```

**Step 4)** Click in "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button.

Full instructions here
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer helped me solve my gradle sync problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27784297/1157720

> Remove .gradle from home directory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried multiple solutions for this.
Finally, following worked for me.

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete (or better move them somewhere to have a backup) .gradle from following path :

Android Studio > File(Menu bar) > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > (In the right pane) Service Directory Path: "Some Path" \ .gradle

Go to "Some Path" and Delete or take back up of .gradle folder .

3. Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh. This will again create the .gradle folder

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be **too late** to answer. But this may help someone.

In my case there was problem of JDK path.

I just **set proper JDK path** for **Android Studio 2.1**

Answer (score 0):

Set chmod to 775 on .gradle dir in the home directory helped to me solved it out.

Comment: Make this correct if you think you solved your own issue.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
allprojects 
{
    repositories 
    {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```