# Gradle cannot resolve dependencies classpath from jcenter() in Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, analytics

I`m using android studio 1.5.1 on ubuntu.
I want to add *google analytic* to my android app.So I followed [google analytic document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project) but when I change mavenCentral() to jcenter() , Android studio cannot resolve this classpath:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

When I press "sync project with Gradle files`Button" , Android studio take about 15 minutes and finally says :

> Error:Connection timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please
>   configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

However I used and did not used proxy , And result was same.

1. Why I cannot connect to jcenter() but I can connect to mavenCentral()?
2. How can I sync gradle with my project to implement Google Analytic ?

Thanks.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

=============================

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Comment: Why are you adding `com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6` to your buildscript classpath?  That doesn't seem to be part of the setup instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your network is restricted to access some sites or download from those sites.

If you are working from your office then it may have a proxy server. and it is restricting from downloading Gradle dependencies.

> A proxy or proxy server is basically another computer which serves as a hub through which internet requests are processed. By connecting through one of these servers, your computer sends your requests to the proxy server which then processes your request and returns what you were wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also
First check your internet proxy settings copy the proxy settings like proxy host and port no. and go to your "gradle.properties" file in project and paste it like this

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost="copied proxy host"
systemProp.http.proxyPort="copied proxy port"

systemProp.https.proxyHost="copied proxy host"
systemProp.https.proxyPort="copied proxy port"
```

Generally people paste the system prop for http but forget for https so please paste both.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes firewalls from antivirus(i'm using AVG) might block the connection. Turn off the antivirus and refresh the project. Hope it might work, it worked in my case.